# How to manage and make look of complex data <table> identical in all browser?

Tags: css, xhtml

What are helpful CSS properties which can be helpful for table?
I have to make so many complex tables which have different type of colors in columns, thead, borders, padding, alternate row and column colors etc. I want to use as less as possible of css classes.

How to make complex tables design with combination of as much as possible of HTML tags and CSS properties? and should look identical in all browsers.

**Update:**

And on same page I have to add multiple `table` with totally different styles

Answer (score 2):

Tables are really, really old technology and tend to be very reliable in my experience. I would just get going, plan the CSS well and deal with any cross-browser issues if and when they come up.

Comment: I'm using table for Tabular data, not for layouts

Comment: @metal-gear-solid I said tables are old in the sense that they are very *reliable*, not that one shouldn't use them. Tables are time-tested and work pretty well, is what I'm saying. I happily use them every day (in some very rare instances even for layout but ssshhhh! That needs to stay a secret :)

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

> The foundational YUI Reset CSS file
>   removes and neutralizes the
>   inconsistent default styling of HTML
>   elements, creating a level playing
>   field across A-grade browsers and
>   providing a sound foundation upon
>   which you can explicitly declare your
>   intentions.

I must admit though, I am not sure I understand your question

Comment: if you are using reset css this will run same in all browser.

Comment: @kc - CSS Reset is not a single solution to solve all cross browser problems. It's a myth.

Answer (score 0):

you should use for this reset style sheet.you can visit this and read about reset stylesheet

[reset staylesheet](http://www.noupe.com/css/15-css-habits-to-develop-for-frustration-free-coding.html)